# Hibernate Criteria Query - nested condition

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I can't figure out how to create a query like this with Hibernate Criteria synthax

```
select * from x where x.a = 'abc'  and (x.b = 'def' or x.b = 'ghi')
```

Do you have an idea of how to do that?
I'm Using Hibernate Restriction static methods but I don't understand how to specify the nested 'or' condition

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You specific query could be:

```
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("a", "abc"));
crit.add(Restrictions.in("b", new String[] { "def", "ghi" });
```

If you're wondering about ANDs and ORs in general, do this:

```
// Use disjunction() or conjunction() if you need more than 2 expressions
Disjunction aOrBOrC = Restrictions.disjunction(); // A or B or C
aOrBOrC.add(Restrictions.eq("b", "a"));
aOrBOrC.add(Restrictions.eq("b", "b"));
aOrBOrC.add(Restrictions.eq("b", "c"));

// Use Restrictions.and() / or() if you only have 2 expressions
crit.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("a", "abc"), aOrBOrC));
```

This will be equivalent to:

```
where x.a = 'abc' and (x.b = 'a' or x.b = 'b' or x.b = 'c')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a syntax more like `(x.b IN ('def', 'ghi'))`.