# Why is my Hibernate Criteria throwing a null pointer exception?

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria

Why does this work fine:

```
Object searchCores() {
    ...
    def core_criteria = sessionFactory.currentSession.createCriteria(Core.class)
    core_criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike('field', '%inputvalue%'))
    ...
}
```

and this doesn't at runtime:

```
Object searchCores() {
    ...
    def core_criteria = sessionFactory.currentSession.createCriteria(Core.class)
    core_criteria.add(X())
    ...
}   

Criterion X() {
    return Restrictions.ilike('field', '%inputvalue%'))
}
```

Error is:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error    
Class java.lang.NullPointerException    
Message null    
at core_criteria.add(X()) line.
```

The point of this question is that at some point I want function X to become a recursive function that adds a long list of nested Restrictions.or Criterions from a list of input.

I am using Grails 2.0.

Thank you

**Ed**. Note that I have just discovered the Disjunction criterion to solve my need (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206702/hibernate-criteria-query-nested-condition) but the question is still pertinent and I would still like to understand what's going on.

Comment: Why are you creating criteria queries the hard way using Hibernate directly, and not using the much simpler GORM syntax?

Comment: @Burt because I'm a noob and I don't know any better? My query comes from a complex 20+ field form with lots of specificities. I couldn't figure how to put all the complexity in those GORM closures...